# The relationship between logics and algebraic structures and results in logic that correspond to results in Universal Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, model-theory, type-theory, higher-order-logic

Propositional logic is intimately related to Boolean algebra, in the sense that both its syntax and semantics can be given an algebraic interpretation.

Are there any algebras that stand to second or higher order logics (or type theory) in the same way that boolean algebras stand to propositional logic?

Is there any well-known way of relating an algebraic structure to a fragment of a higher order logic?

On a related note, are there ways of relating the completeness of FOL to corresponding results in universal algebra, and ways of relating the theorem that second-order validity is not recursively enumerable to corresponding results in universal algebra?

Comment: I suspect the failure of the compactness theorem (not to mention the frankly ridiculous complexity of the satisfaction relation) in second-order logic will prevent any "nice" algebraic interpretation.

Comment: Thanks :). I just re-edited my post to encompass a related question which I'd be delighted if you were to know the answer to :).

Comment: I don't quite understand the connection between BCT and GCT you suggest. The fact that there is a complete recursive proof system for equational logic follows directly from GCT. (Also, when you say "incompleteness of second order logic" and "incompleteness theorem," presumably you mean the theorem that second-order validity is not r.e. - note that this isn't usually what people hear when someone says "incompleteness theorem".)

Comment: My confusion. I will erase what I wrote. I am just interested in whether any of the completeness or incompleteness results have correspondent results in abstract or universal algebra.

Comment: I have re-edited my post in the hope that it is better. :)

Comment: This question is hopelessly vague (hence my close vote): "first order logic bears an intimate relation to various algebras" is a meaningless platitude and the question doesn't pick up after that.

Comment: I have deleted that particular sentence.

Comment: This question is hopelessly vague (hence my close vote).